# JPG sequence in PHP

Tags: php

Sorry for the elementary question but I am not completely proficient in PHP. I have a PHP script that puts a photo in a folder on my website which gets sent from an iPhone. The problem is the script basically overwrites the previous jpg each time a new photo is uploaded. The file name is always image.jpg. How can I make the php script force a sequence each time a new photo is uploaded from the app (i.e. image_1.jpg, image_2.jpg, etc).

```
<?php
$name = "image";
$path = "uploaded/".$name.".jpg";
$output = "{\"response\":\"false\"}";   
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
     $output = "{\"response\":\"true\"}";
}
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: Look into using the [`tempnam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the path and name on lines 2 and 3, so use this to check if the file already exists, and if it does set $name to image_$i and increment $i

```
<?php
$i = 0;
do {
    $name = 'image' . (($i > 0) ? '_' . $i : '');
    $path = 'uploaded/' . $name . '.jpg';
    $i++;
} while (file_exists($path));
$output = "{\"response\":\"false\"}";   
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
     $output = "{\"response\":\"true\"}";
}
echo $output;
```

Comment: Thanks Jamie. That did it.